# Using GNU/Linux as an Electronics Engineer?

Tags: linux, tools

Are there many companies that provide a GNU/Linux environment for their electronic engineers?

Comment: There are at least 73.

Comment: This is a good question for a more discussion-oriented site than stackexchange. Because it immediately leads to anecdotes and opinions about why things are the way they are, or advice about how to work around issues with the way things are, etc.

Comment: You could join our chat (if you get just a couple more rep), or try the allaboutcircuits.com discussion boards, or a site like Reddit (/r/ece or /r/askelectronics, maybe).

Comment: Use the OS you like, if the tools you need support it.

Comment: @ThePhoton you should mention the [url to our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) too.

Comment: @jippie, I would if I knew it, but I usually get there by clicking the word "chat" on the top line of the page.

Comment: @ThePhoton you have two more upvotes time to find it ;o)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about operating system popularity rather than electronic design.